# Remove font-size from string

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to figure out how to .replace() the font-size from a string while I am re-writing a stylesheet.  I'm not so great with regex, I tried this:

```
string.replace(/font-size:.*S.;/, '');
```

it didn't work, I've been messing around with it for a bit, any help appreciated..

Comment: Share some input samples and expected outputs.

Comment: I just expect [ font-size: (anything) ; ] to be replaced with nothing, I thought my code example was clear...thanks for the down vote

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but you still need to share sample inputs and their expected outputs.

Comment: Where exactly is the code run? If you're running it in a browser, I guess it's much easier to just access a live [stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) and the rules in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
font-size\s?:\s?\d+(px|em);
```

Please check the link
https://regexr.com/3h6cq

It supports px/em, if you need any other units just add them with the pipe symbol.

**Update**:
You can also go with a more general approach which will accept anything after the `:` up until the semi-colon `;`

```
font-size\s?:([^;]+)
```

https://regexr.com/3h6ct

**Update 2** if you want to support decimals (and only `px` units) you could do:

```
font-size\s?:\s?\d+\.?\d+(px);
```

https://regexr.com/3h6d3

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this seems to work except for font-size:10.5px;  where a decimal is used

Comment: your update works great but it does leave the semicolon from the font-size:10.5px; By the way, with your updated version is there a way to exclude em font-sizes? e.g.: font-size:1em;

Comment: Awesome, this works but when I added pt it didn't remove pt also. I added like this:  /font-size\s?:\s?\d+\.?\d+(px|pt);/

Comment: @RON2015 yes you need to add the measurements you want. Please mark as correct answer if that answered your question.